# Flutter: Debug build successful but release gives error

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

After updating the flutter to 1.12.13+hotfix.8, Flutter gives strange errors on release build, but works perfectly fine in debug build

**Error** :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'intent'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or 
by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 
'/Users/niyantras/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intent- 
1.1.0/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to 
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

**Flutter doctor :**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-GB)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.42.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Can someone help me in figuring out, thanks for the help.

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` and then 
`flutter pub cache repair`. Also look that whether intent package has an available upgrade if so change to that version

Comment: every package is up to date, if I every remove Intent then same error is shown for different package, but I build a simple app without any dependencies it worked fine, what could be reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> flutter clean
>
> flutter pub cache repair

let me know if the issue persists

[check here, it's closed issues of flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47122)

Check for `compilesdkversion` everywhere in the folder and match it with one in `android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: delete your gradle cache. (.idea, .gradle)

Comment: so I searched for compilesdkversion everywhere and found in couple of files it was different that in android/app/build.gradle after changing that it worked fine

Comment: Great Working! some time generate systematically cache issues

Comment: btw, any idea what could have caused that maybe for now its resolved but could appear like nightmare anytime, I have been resolving this since yesterday evening couldn't find anything so came here